# Как прижать элементы внутри блока к противоположным сторонам?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Пытаюсь сделать макет слайдера, блок с картинкой и внутри него кнопки прижатые по краям, что я могу использую `float`, есть ли способ удобнее.

Мой пример

```css
.slider {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.arrow {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

.right-arrow {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="arrow left-arrow">

  </div>
  <div class="arrow right-arrow">

  </div>
</div>
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `flexbox` с распределением элементов по ширине (`justify-content: space-between`) , где первый элемент прижат к левому краю и последний к правому. В вашем случае 2 блока вложенных, так что сработает так как вам нужно.

### Пример `flexbox` и `justify-content: space-between`

```css
.slider {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.arrow {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="arrow left-arrow">

  </div>
  <div class="arrow right-arrow">

  </div>
</div>
```